# Using click and mouse events together

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to make a map in which one would be able to hover over a district which would highlight that district but also give the user the option of clicking on that district which would highlight it in a different color.

Currently, the mouseover/mouseout and click events work as they should. My only problem is that I would like the click highlight not to be reset as soon as the mouseout event is fired up.

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
// Action for each feature of the choropleth
function onEachFeature(feature, layer)
{
    layer.on({
            mouseover: highlight,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: highlightSelection
    });
}

// Highlight function that highlights a specific district
function highlight(e)
{
    this.setStyle({
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 0.5,
        color: '#666',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    });
}

// Reset any highlights after mouseout
function resetHighlight(e)
{
    geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
}

// Highlighting the selected administrative area
function highlightSelection(e)
{
    e.target.setStyle({
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 0.5,
        color: '#666',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });
}
```

My problem is obviously in the resetHighlight() as it reset the style of the whole map, which is not exactly what I want as I would like to keep the click event highlight until another district has been clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I got it to work. When the user clicks on a district and wants to click on another, the previous district will not be highlighted anymore. The mouseover/mouseout events will continue to work throughout the process.

Here is the code:

```
// Action for each feature of the choropleth
function onEachFeature(feature, layer)
{
    layer.on({
            mouseover: highlight,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: highlightSelection
    });
}
// Highlight function that highlights a specific district
function highlight(e)
{
    hoverID = this._leaflet_id;

    // if statement used to stop highlighting of clicked district
    if(hoverID != clickID)
    {
        this.setStyle({
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 0.5,
            color: '#666',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        });
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

// Reset any highlights after mouseout
function resetHighlight(e)
{
    // If statement to dehighlight after hovering
    if(hoverID != clickID)
    {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    }
    // If statement to dehighlight after a click
    else if(clickID != clickID2)
    {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    }
}
// Highlighting the selected administrative area
function highlightSelection(e)
{
    // ID used to check if highlighted or not
    clickID = this._leaflet_id;
    if(firstPass == true)
    {
        resetHighlight(previous);
    }
    previous = e;
    // ID to compare with clickID to check if a new click was made
    clickID2 = this._leaflet_id;

    e.target.setStyle({
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 0.5,
        color: '#666',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });
    firstPass = true;
}
```